# Matching Any Word Regex

Tags: regex, dreamweaver, replace

I would like to remove hundreds on onmouseover events from my code. the evt all pass different variables and I want to be able to use dreamwaever to find and replace all the strings with nothing.

Here is an example

```
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'Wilson');"
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'Harris');"
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'Walker');"
```

I want to run a search that will identify all of these and replace/remove them.

I have tried seemingly infinite permutations of things like:

```
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'[^']');"
```

or

```
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'[^']);"
```

or

```
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,[^']);"
```

or

```
onmouseover="parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt,'[^']+');"
```

And many more. I cannot find the regular expression that will work.

Any/all help would be appreciated.

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"."` and "`(`" have special meaning in regular expressions, so you need to escape them:

```
onmouseover="parent\.mv_mapTipOver\(evt,'[^']+'\);"
```

I'm not sure if this is correct dreamweaver regex syntax, but this stuff is standard enough.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
onmouseover="parent\.mv_mapTipOver\(evt,'.+?'\);"
```

And see it in action [here](http://regexr.com?34f48).

Comment: both of these answers are correct. I accepted creinig answer b/c it came a bit before + he explained the escaping which was helpful. I appreciated it

Answer (score 1):

When using reg expressions you have to be very careful about how you handle white space. For example the following piece of code will not get caught by most of the reg expressions mentioned so far because of the space after the comma and equals sign, despite the fact that it is most likely valid syntax in the language you are using.

```
onmouseover= "parent.mv_mapTipOver(evt, 'Walker');"
```

In order to create regexp that ignore white space you must insert /s* everywhere in the regexp that white space might occur.

The following regexp should work even if there is additional white space in your code.

```
onmouseover\s*=\s*"parent\.mv_mapTipOver\(\s*evt\s*,\s*'[A-Za-z]+'\s*\);"
```